# How to completely remove a Snap app

Tags: software-installation, uninstall, snap, purge, kdenlive

I installed, and later removed, the kdenlive Snap from my Ubuntu 20.04 system. The removal went like this:

```
sudo snap remove --purge kdenlive
```

I notice there's still these two remnants of kdenlive on my system (maybe more):

1. `~/snap/kdenlive` (directory)
2. `~/snap/kdenlive/current` (file)

Why wasn't the `~/snap/kdenlive` directory deleted when I issued the command above? Should I delete this directory if I want kdenlive completely gone from my system? Is there anything else I have to do for complete removal?

Comment: Debian-based developers are taught that it's okay to add files and directories to your /home (~), but rudely intrusive to delete them. This prevents a whole class of wailing and drama when an accidental or erroneous removal irretrievably deletes a whole bunch of your data (or metadata) unexpectedly.

Comment: According to snap documentation, that is the correct command to remove it. It should be safe to remove the `~/snap/kdenlive` directory. If `kdenlive` is not present when you run `snap list`, then the snap is removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operating system will *never* delete files, including configuration files, in your own home folder. These files are considered yours and are under your control. This works the same for applications installed using the traditional APT system. Feel free to delete these remnants.

Other remnants will remain at the level of the system files, including possible ["snapshots"](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapshots) of previous versions of this snap. The snap system is, however, setup to clean these up after a certain period of time, although you also can clean them up yourself.